# How can you rewrite an integral that is relative to f(x,y) and has f(x,y) as a bound?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Is there a way to rewrite or make sense of the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{f(x,y)} g(f(x,y)) df(x,y)$$

I arrived at it using a u substitution, but it's difficult for me to decipher or simplify.

Comment: use: $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ for the indefinite integral, to get a line integral

Comment: In one variable, for instance, $\int_0^x g(x) \ dx$ wouldn't make sense because you've double-used $x$.  Instead, you'd have something like $\int_0^x g(t) \ dt$, using $t$ as a dummy variable.

Comment: Oh good catch! I totally messed up the math before this point.